# Twitter integration error

Tags: android, twitter, twitter-oauth, twitter4j

Following error coming while ,  Twitter api integrating with my own application !!
and all library are place in project still getting error !

any solution plz ??

twitter4j n outh was used  !

I already added all libraries , still error coming  ,
But if i separately  run twitter api , its run normal way !!

But when i integrated in any app ,that time same error is coming  !!!!!

What should i do ??

---

```
10-04 10:58:54.524: ERROR/dalvikvm(844): Could not find class 'twitter4j.TwitterFactory', referenced from method com.jcp.dp.android.twitter.TwitterUtils.isAuthenticated


10-04 10:58:54.524: WARN/dalvikvm(844): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 1102 (Ltwitter4j/TwitterFactory;) in Lcom/jcp/dp/android/twitter/TwitterUtils;

10-04 10:58:54.524: DEBUG/dalvikvm(844): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0017

10-04 10:58:54.524: DEBUG/dalvikvm(844): Making a copy of Lcom/jcp/dp/android/twitter/TwitterUtils;.isAuthenticated code (193 bytes)

10-04 10:58:54.524: ERROR/dalvikvm(844): Could not find class 'twitter4j.auth.AccessToken', referenced from method com.jcp.dp.android.twitter.TwitterUtils.sendTweet

10-04 10:58:54.524: WARN/dalvikvm(844): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 1103 (Ltwitter4j/auth/AccessToken;) in Lcom/jcp/dp/android/twitter/TwitterUtils;

10-04 10:58:54.524: DEBUG/dalvikvm(844): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0010

10-04 10:58:54.524: DEBUG/dalvikvm(844): Making a copy of Lcom/jcp/dp/android/twitter/TwitterUtils;.sendTweet code (104 bytes)

10-04 10:58:54.524: DEBUG/TAG19(844):  yes

10-04 10:58:54.534: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(844): Shutting down VM

10-04 10:58:54.534: WARN/dalvikvm(844): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001b188)

10-04 10:58:54.534: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(844): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception

10-04 10:58:54.544: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(844): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: twitter4j.TwitterFactory

10-04 10:58:54.544: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(844):     at com.jcp.dp.android.twitter.TwitterUtils.isAuthenticated(TwitterUtils.java:23)

10-04 10:58:54.544: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(844):     at com.jcp.dp.android.twitter.AndroidTwitterSample$1.onClick(AndroidTwitterSample.java:43)

10-04 10:58:54.544: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(844):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2364)

10-04 10:58:54.544: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(844):     at android.view.View.onTouchEvent(View.java:4179)

10-04 10:58:54.544: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(844):     at android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent(TextView.java:6540)

10-04 10:58:54.544: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(844):     at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3709)


10-04 10:58:54.544: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(844):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)

10-04 10:58:54.544: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(844):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)

10-04 10:58:54.544: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(844):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
10-04 10:58:54.544: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(844):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)

10-04 10:58:54.544: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(844):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)

10-04 10:58:54.544: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(844):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)

10-04 10:58:54.544: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(844):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)

10-04 10:58:54.544: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(844):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1659)

10-04 10:58:54.544: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(844):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1107)

10-04 10:58:54.544: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(844):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2061)

10-04 10:58:54.544: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(844):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1643)

10-04 10:58:54.544: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(844):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1691)

10-04 10:58:54.544: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(844):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

10-04 10:58:54.544: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(844):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)

10-04 10:58:54.544: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(844):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
.
10-04 10:58:54.544: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(844):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

10-04 10:58:54.544: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(844):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)

10-04 10:58:54.544: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(844):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)

10-04 10:58:54.544: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(844):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)

10-04 10:58:54.544: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(844):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: the error message says that there's no class defined..please check that you have added that jar file to your project via Build Path

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just came across a similar issue.

In addition to adding the JAR file to the project you have to make sure that it will be included in the apk file:
Go to your project properties -> Java Build Path -> Order and Export tab, and ensure the box next to the twitter4j JAR file is checked.

Answer (score -2):

you need to configure the build path by right clicking on the project in eclipse -> buildpath -> configure build path -> go to libraries -> add jars -> add the jar file of the twitter.